# Move x-axis label on DC.js chart

Tags: dc.js

Wondering how I get the x-axis label to not overlap with the tick marks (see below)

Any help much appreciated

[image: Overlap x label]

EDIT:

As per Gordon's solution below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's counterintuitive, but you need to set the [margins](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/MarginMixin.html#margins__anchor) to allow space for the tick labels and Y axis label.

dc.js does not automatically lay out elements that rely on text size, because it is complicated and expensive to do so.

Instead it requires the user to set margins that leave room. The margins are used to shrink and offset the chart area.

The default margins are `{top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 30}`; these settings are just a guess. You might try

```
chart.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 60})
```

and then continue to tweak until it looks right.

Also notice that when you set the `xAxisLabel` [(docs)](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#xAxisLabel__anchor) and `yAxisLabel` [(docs)](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#yAxisLabel__anchor), there is an optional second padding argument. You might want to increase either/both from the default of 12.

Comment: genius! thanks a bunch, edit post as per your solution. Will this keep the chart axes a specific size from the container, or is there other calculation in there? I'm wondering because I would like to line up the Y-axes of multiple charts in a column

Comment: If you do not set `.width(...)` and `.height(...)` or pass `null` they are calculated from the client rect of the container. So you can either set absolute values or make sure the containers are the same width. Once you have your charts the same size, then setting the left and right margins the same on all charts should keep the axes aligned.